# react way of setting focus on a particular button in stateful component?

Tags: reactjs, focus, pageload

I tried different ways of setting focus to button on pageload like ref ,but it doesnt work. Thats is whenever pageloads focus should be on this button.
Can anyone help me with a sample example

```
class SubPageHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }
  render() {
   return (
    <input type="button"/>
   );
  };
}
```

Can anyone help me with a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` will execute only once when your page loads first time, to maintain a focus on every re-render you also need to use `componentDidUpdate`.

```
class SubPageHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myInput = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.myInput.current.focus(); //To focus first time page loads
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
     this.myInput.current.focus(); //To focus on every re-render
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="button" ref={this.myInput} />
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using refs:

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    input = React.createRef()

    componentDidMount(){
        this.input.current.focus()
    }

    render(){ return <input ref={this.input} /> }
}
```

Or [plain `HTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) : `<input autoFocus />`

Answer (score 1):

To focus on component mount the simplest way is

```
class SubPageHeader extends React.Component {

  render() {
   return (
    <input autoFocus type="button"/>
   );
  };
}
```